# How to pass variable into model listener

Tags: laravel

I can't seem to find anything online regarding this. I am trying to figure out how to pass a variable into a model's listener.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Auth::user()->image()->create([], $image, $extension, config('app.profile_pictures_path'));
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is my observer:

```
public function creating(Image $image, $imageFile, $extension, $folder = null)
{
    $image->path = $folder . FileNameGenerator::getNewFilePath($extension); 
    //gets a unique random file name

    Storage::disk('s3')->put( $image->path, File::get($imageFile));

    return $image;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code of your listener.

Comment: @thefallen done :)

Comment: I'm going to take another approach where I use a helper class to save the model and upload the image. Wish me luck! Will post the answer.

Comment: I would suggest having a look at https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/introduction and more specifically https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/working-with-media-collections/defining-media-collections#single-file-collections

Comment: @RossWilson Thanks, I think I will try that approach if I ever need to try this again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. I hope this is considered decent code.

```
public static function saveImage( $model, $pluralModel, $image, $extension, $folder, array $attributes = null)
{
    $path = $folder . self::getNewFilePath($folder, $extension);
    Storage::disk('s3')->put( $path, File::get($image));

    $attributes['path'] = $path;
    $attributes['size_kb'] = self::getFileSizeKb($image);


    if($pluralModel){
        $model->images()->create($attributes);
    }else{
        if($model->image()->exists()) self::deleteFile($model->image);
        $model->image()->create($attributes);
    }

    return true;
}

public static function deleteFile($model)
{
    Storage::disk('s3')->delete($model->path);
    $model->delete();
}
```